# Chrome extension keyboard shortcut takes 2 presses to change value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm having a weird issue trying to implement the [Chrome keyboard shortcuts](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/commands) API in a Chrome extension I'm developing. Put shortly, I have to press the designated keyboard shortcut 2 times to change the stored value.

Here's my keyboard shortcut listener:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get([command], function(result) {
        toggle = result[command];
    });

    toggle = toggle_value(toggle)

    chrome.storage.sync.set({[command]: toggle }, function() {
        console.log( {[command]: toggle} );
    });
});
```

And my `toggle_value()` function:

```
function toggle_value(value) {
    if(value == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if(value == 1) {
        return 0;
    }   
}
```

My keyboard shortcut listener receives a `command` as set in the manifest, gets the corresponding value of the same key name from the [Chrome synced storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) database, toggles the value then it sets it back to the Chrome synced storage using the same key name.

As stated earlier, the value of the `command` key is only really toggled after pressing the keyboard shortcut 2 consecutive times. I spent hours debugging this with no luck, please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Chrome API is [asynchronous](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#sync), see the linked topic for solutions.

Comment: @wOxxOm I wouldn't exactly call this a duplicate but the question you linked does indeed address the issue I have in my code.

Comment: That's what a duplicate is here. It doesn't have to be an exact copy as long as the answer applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem.** The functions you are using are asynchronous, but your code is running synchronously. Your code should work if nested.

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get([command], function(result) {
        toggle = result[command];
        toggle = toggle_value(toggle);
        chrome.storage.sync.set({[command]: toggle }, function() {
            console.log( {[command]: toggle} );
        });
    });
});
```

**Suggestion.** You should look into `Promises` to handle asynchronous code more elegantly.

Comment: Very interesting, I know how asynchronous JavaScript works but I'm new to the Chrome API and I didn't expect it to be such. I totally understand the solution and it works, thank you.